# SFML 2.0 Loading from a map file

Tags: c++, file, dictionary, external, sfml

Okay hello everyone! I have another problem again.. I'm getting an unhandled exception.

I tracked the problem back to it's source which is:

```
openfile >> MapFile[loadCounterX][loadCounterY];
```

The exception is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76ee15de in The Vanity Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x336e880c.
```

It says it's an violation of access yet the thing I'm accessing was succesfully opened here:

```
std::ifstream openfile(filename);
```

The entire function is:

```
//Load map
void Map::Load(const char *filename)
{
    //Open the file
    std::ifstream openfile(filename);
    //Check if file is open
    if(openfile.is_open())
    {
        //Get mapSizeX and Y from the file
        openfile >> mapSizeX >> mapSizeY;
        //While not at the end of the file
        while(!openfile.eof())
        {
            //Store number at loadCounterX and loadCounterY
            openfile >> MapFile[loadCounterX][loadCounterY]; //Error here
            //Increment loadCounterX++
            loadCounterX++;
            //If loadCounterX is less than mapSizeX
            if(loadCounterX >= mapSizeX)
            {
                //Set loadCounterX to 0
                loadCounterX = 0;
                //Increment loadCounterY 
                loadCounterY++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MapFile is in Map.H

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "Global.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Map
{
public:
    void Load(const char *filename);
    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &Window);
private:
    int loadCounterX, loadCounterY;
    int mapSizeX, mapSizeY;
    int MapFile[100][100];
};

#endif
```

Comment: What is `MapFile` and where/how is it initialized?

Comment: Updated OP with the Map.H

Comment: mapSizeX  and mapSizeY always < 100?

Comment: Please change MapFile to a dynamic container (`std::vector`, for example).

Comment: It's just a value to set the maximum mapSizeX and mapSizeY.

Comment: what are their value then?

Comment: This was part of a tutorial for loading from files but the easiest one. (It builds up to get more advanced e.g using vectors.

Comment: SOrry Billz yes they are. I set them both to 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadCounter*` should be local to function or at least initialized to 0 everytime you load.

For the first time this could work ok, however the variables are not reset to 0 before next loading, resulting in addressing unallocated space.

*Side note:*

Please, use some sort of dynamic allocation (such as std::vector) for your map data. It just doesn't make sense to use 100x100 every time, does it?

Comment: No it doesn't but I'm following a tutorial in which it builds up on it. I know how to use vectors yet I would rather keep with the tutorial in case I move of it too much and end up being stuck and confused with it. Thanks though!

Comment: Well, in that case, I'd look for a better tutorial. Anyway, addressing part can be the same with vector of vectors.